# Vector field of a simple pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, vector-fields, angular-velocity, differential-equations

Classical Mechanics by John Taylor walks through an example of a skateboard on a frictionless half-pipe of radius $R=5.0$m. This is equivalent to a frictionless pendulum, I believe.

The example goes on to reach a differential equation: $\ddot{\phi} = -\frac{g}{R} \sin \phi$, where $\phi$ is the angular position:

[image]

The author states that the differential equation $\ddot{\phi} = -\frac{g}{R} \sin \phi$ can't be solved analytically, so I have tried to plot the vector field to get a feel for what's going on.

Can someone confirm that this is correct? The slope of a vector at $(t, \phi(t))$ represents $\ddot{\phi}$.

[image]

It looks to me like, for any value on the $y$-axis, there is a small oscillation around that value. I think this makes sense qualitatively, but I want to confirm that I'm not fooling myself; it's trick to to look at acceleration values on a times vs. position graph.

Edit: one thing that's bothering me: it seems like acceleration oscillates without the position ever reaching $0$, for example, the horizontal line where $\phi = 4$. This doesn't seem correct...

Comment: I am not sure what  exactly you are plotting and how it relates to what you are trying to prove. First of all, could you specify how exactly the arrows are related to $\ddot{\phi}$?  Also, if you are fine with elliptic integrals there does exist an "analytic" solution.

Comment: The slope of the vector at $(t, \phi(t))$ represents $\ddot{\phi}$. I'm just trying to get comfortable with analyzing these types of pictures. I'm not really looking for an analytic solution.

Comment: How do you calculate $\ddot{\phi}$ at $(t,\phi(t))$? Wouldn't that depend on the initial conditions? Typically people plot $\dot{\phi}$ vs $\phi$.

Comment: "Check my work" questions are not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 3):

The vector field you're plotting isn't all that meaningful, to be honest.  If you can edit your question to explain why this is what you chose to plot, I can perhaps answer better as to how to accomplish your goal here.

However, a fairly standard way to investigate the behavior of a 1-D particle (albeit not one taught in Taylor until *much* later) is to rewrite the equations of motion as follows:
$$
\ddot{\phi} = - \frac{g}{R} \sin \phi \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \begin{cases} \frac{d\phi}{dt} = \omega & \\ \frac{d\omega}{dt} = - \frac{g}{R} \sin \phi \end{cases}
$$ 
You can then plot a vector field with $\phi$ along the horizontal axis and $\omega$ along the vertical axis, where the vector field is
$$
\vec{v}(\phi, \omega) = (\omega, - \frac{g}{R}\sin \phi).
$$
The advantage of this way of plotting things is that the slope of a vector in this plane is equal to the rate of change of $\omega$ with respect to $\phi$, since by definition
$$
\frac{d \omega}{d \phi} = \frac{d \omega/dt}{d \phi/dt} = \frac{-\frac{g}{R} \sin \phi}{\omega} = \frac{v_\omega}{v_\phi}.
$$ 
The vector plot then looks something like this (with $g/R = 1$):

[image]

We can see from this that the pendulum can oscillate around the point $\phi = 0, \omega = 0$;  as this oscillation happens, you go around the circular curve at the center.  While there are moments where $\phi = 0$ and moments where $\omega = 0$, they never happen at the same time.

This whole technique is what's known as a *phase space technique*;  it's a handy tool for investigating the properties of solutions in a qualitative way.  It's discussed briefly in Chapter 13.6 of Taylor, in the context of *Hamiltonian dynamics*.  It's also discussed in more detail in Thornton & Marion's *Classical Dynamics of Particles & Systems*;  in my older (4th) edition, it's in Chapter 3, well before Hamiltonian dynamics is introduced.

Comment: I'm parsing through this now. One thing I think I have realized is that it seems the "mistake" I made is that I'm trying to visualize **second derivatives** with a technique that is usually used for **first derivatives**. I think you introduce the $\omega = \frac{d \phi}{dt}$ term precisely because of this? I suppose what we lose is the inability to see what happens in phase space *over time*?